# Javascript: Could not really understand the function return

Tags: javascript

It is maybe incredibly easy but I couldn't solve what was going on.

```
function doSomething(a)
{
   var num=10;
   return setTimeout(
   function(){ a(num); }, 1000);
}
```

The only thing that actually confuses me is the **a(num)** part. What actually it does?
**Reminder:**  I really am asking because I'm not familiar with the javascript syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `function` `doSomething()` is executed it is passed the parameter `a`, 
`a` is also some `function` that is then called when `setTimeout()` expires after 1 second,
then calling the `function` `a()` passing the argument called `num`

[Example usage](http://jsfiddle.net/NxdEn/):

```
// call doSomething() passing the test() function as an argument
doSomething(test);


// takes a number as an argument and shows an alert with that value
function test(number)
{
   alert(number);
}

// takes a function as an argument that will perform a 1 second timeout then execute the function called a
function doSomething(a)
{
   var num=10;
   return setTimeout(
   function(){ a(num); }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It calls the function referenced by the variable `a`, using the value referenced by the variable `num` as an argument.

Comment: But in here, a is the input for the doSomething. So how does it work as a function?

Comment: @rolandbishop JavaScript's functions are first-class. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Comment: @rolandbishop: Functions are values just like everything else, so they can be passed around in variables.

Answer (score 0):

**setTimeout** returns a **timeoutID** which can be used to cancel it using **clearTimeout**, so if you run *doSomething* a lot of times you will get different integer numbers which represent different **timeoutID**.

In your case **a** must be a function so you can call it using the parameter **num**

Example:

```
function doSomethingElse (justANumber) {
    return justANumber + 1;
}

// Here you call your function
doSomething(doSomethingElse);

// or another special case
doSomething(function (justANumber) {return justANumber + 1;});
```